# Docker mounting throws "chown: changing ownership ... Permission denied"

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run a local Postgres database using Docker and have the information stored on the machine for future use - the machine is Ubuntu.

The command I run:

```
docker run -dt --rm --expose 5432 -p 5432:5432 --mount type=bind,source=/home/postgres/data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data --name postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 docker.io/library/postgres:13
```

but I get the following error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Permission denied
```

- Each time I installed a fresh new Docker and *then* ran the command
- I run everything as root (how can root not have permissions?...)
- Running the image without mounting and changing the permission of the folder while it's running throws no errors
- I did the **EXACT** same thing on both CentOS and RedHat Linux machines and they didn't throw this error nor had any problems

Any idea how to solve this?